# PRF with one value changed

Tags: pseudo-random-function

I'm having problem proving the following, I intuitively think this is correct but can't formally prove why.

given a PRF   $F_k(x)$

proove that the following is also a PRF

$$
F'_k(x) = \begin{cases}
F_k(x)&\text{if }k\neq0\\
\\\text{const(some const value)}&\text{if }k=0
\end{cases}
$$

---

I found my mistake, I did not use the probability axioms correctly
here is the full solution

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hint: you are correct. Prove it by showing that any algorithm that distinguish $F'$ from random with non-vanishing advantage can be turned into (or is) one that distinguish $F$ from random with non-vanishing advantage.